# Need Help To Resolve ORA-12154

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I installed Oracle 12cR2.
Everything is fine.
Connected as SYS, Successful.

Now, what I did is changed my Container DB i.e. CDB$ROOT to ORCLPDB (Using Alter Session). And Created a User Called `demo` with password. Granted necessary permissions. Successful.

In that same session, I tried to connect to `demo` User, but unable to connect to it.

Error Shows as Follow:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

How can I resolve this issue?
(Note: The user is in PDB)

tnsnames.ora

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SID = orcl)    
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the user. What is the exact command you use to connect to the database as that user?

Comment: conn Demo/password and conn Demo/Password@ORCLPDB

Comment: There is no alias `ORCLPDB` in your tnsnames.ora

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: And that's the reason for the error

Comment: So, how to solve it?

Comment: Connect to `Demo/Password@ORCL` (as you have `ORCL` in TNSNAMES.ORA). Or, modify the file and add the new database alias (`ORCLPDB`) if it is a different database, or add yet another alias for the same database, e.g. `ORCL, ORCLPDB = ...`

Comment: How to solve it? - obviously you have to add the appropriate entry

Comment: Great, As per your suggestion i added the following code to my TNSNAMES.ORA, and it worked. ORCLPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
 (SID = orclpdb) 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
    )
  )

Comment: so, whenever you create a pluggable database, you need to enter those details in TNSNAMES.ORA. I did not know that. And you also need to change the SERVICE_NAME and SID.

Comment: Can anyone of you or both write the answer by clicking the answer button? That would be helpful for other people.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you fixed it. I've also added an answer which contains what we've said so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you are trying to connect to `Demo/Password@ORCLPDB`
- there is no alias `ORCLPDB` in your tnsnames.ora, so Oracle complains that it can't find it
- therefore:

  - connect to `Demo/Password@ORCL` (as you have `ORCL` in tnsnames.ora), or
  - modify the file and

    - add the new database alias (`ORCLPDB`) if it is a different database, or
    - add yet another alias for the same database, e.g. `ORCL, ORCLPDB = ...`